smartctl lies that NVME has lifespan of ~2800TBW? What is the real lifespan of my NVME?
smartctl -x on my Samsung SSD 860 EVO M.2 2TB shows:
Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4            1132  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4            6584  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     59675855461  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6      1711777462  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6     51882440157  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6      1869976194  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x01  0x038  6          293000  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4              97  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              40  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              64  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              18  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              70  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4           20530  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4               0  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x07  0x008  1               1  N--  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

A paltry 28TB written sounds a little low for the past year I've had this NVME but it's believable. However, the Percentaged Used Endurance Indicator is only at 1%. That would suggest there's still around 100x that or 2800TBW left in this device, which is more than twice the rated 1200TBW so it can't be a rounding error.
Is smartctl lying? (Not that it would lie; I mean, is my NVME lying to smartctl, is smartctl misinterpreting my NVME, etc and etc?) How do I find out the real TBW life remaining in my NVME for sure?

where in your pic indicates 28TB written ?

@ron Multiply Logical Sectors Written by 512 bytes per sector and you'll get roughly 28 TB.

Thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to include that bit about how my SSD's sector size is 512 bytes. You can use lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,FSUSED,FSSIZE,SIZE,PHY-SEC,TYPE,MOUNTPOINTS to get a nice view of your disk infos. Afaik, 512 is the defacto standard for sector size for almost all ssds and hdds as Windows software doesnt optimize for sector size and some Windows software would likely break if the sector size isn't 512 (not that sector size is any relevant concept to modern hdd/sdd, rather it could theoredically be a very very useful tuning variable for buffer sizing.)

Wild guess: perhaps the percentage is rounded down. If the endurance is 1400TBW, then your ~27.8TBW is 1.98%, which might get truncated to 1%. It doesn't quite fit your numbers, but it's pretty close.

I am not aware of some hard specific number to use that could be reliably taking as the 100% mark of SSD lifespan based on bits written to it.  Not sure if that's how it really works, barring an if statement logic bomb in firmware to go make you buy a new one.
I asked this a while back, going by gigabytes processed in my opinion is a better way to judge lifespan based on how heavily the SSD is used.  A pic in my post shows output that you did not include in yours
How to generate daily report of total bytes written (TBW,DWPD) to disk (SSD) in Linux
have to wait till tomorrow when I can check my ssd's that have been in service for 3 years what its endurance number shows... here is that smartctl output for reference for a disk that is part of a raid5 that is on 24/7:
smartctl --xall -d megaraid,7 /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               TOSHIBA
Product:              KPM5WRUG3T84
Revision:             B326
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        3,840,755,982,336 bytes [3.84 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is resource provisioned, LBPRZ=1
Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x58ce38ee209a61b5
Serial number:        EDKH
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Thu Jul 18 09:27:38 2024 EDT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled
Read Cache is:        Enabled
Writeback Cache is:   Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Percentage used endurance indicator: 8%
Current Drive Temperature:     25 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        70 C

Manufactured in week 24 of year 2019
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:          0        8         8         8          8     737163.705           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0      33273.244           0
verify:        0        8         8         8          8     691461.664           0

Non-medium error count:      114

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background long   Completed                   -      22                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                   -      22                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self-test duration: 300 seconds [5.0 minutes]

Background scan results log
  Status: no scans active
    Accumulated power on time, hours:minutes 29843:58 [1790638 minutes]
    Number of background scans performed: 0,  scan progress: 0.00%
    Number of background medium scans performed: 0

about 3.3 TB written over 1243 days of on time, endurance indicator shows 8%.  For a disk that is part of a raid-5 data volume that is on 24/7 in the work environment.

The majority of the work your ssd is doing in the 24/7 environment is reads given its 720TB read, which shouldnt degrade the life of the ssd one bit. Your 3.3TB written is much lower than my 28TB, yet your ssd has an endurance indicator of 8% and mine has 1%. I certainly didn't pay top-datacenter-dollar for my SSD, so I wouldn't expect my SSD to be so significantly more resilient than yours.

what catches my interest is that disks fail for a variety of reasons,  and is there anyone that can say first hand they've experienced an SSD end of life due to writes written?  Can you still smartctl it and see a 100% endurance number?  I'm tempted to find a used ssd and sacrifice it setting it up somewhere to receive nonstop writes.

Numbers seem plausible. smartctl certainly isn't lying, it just prints whatever the drive firmware reports.
Note that the Percentage Used Endurance Indicator is always an integer, and it's entirely possible that it's produced by simple truncation of the fractional part instead of proper rounding. So it might as well be that your drive is currently at 1.99% used, matching the rated endurance almost exactly.
However, more importantly, the rated lifespan is just a crude estimate (nobody can predict the future very well), and if the manufacturer is decent, it's fairly likely to be an underestimate. (Nobody minds drives failing long after their rated lifespan, but failing significantly before reaching the rated endurance can generate bad press.)
Either way, it's not really possible to extrapolate that 1% used all the way to the total endurance with any sort of accuracy. Yes, the firmware certainly knows more about how many sectors have actually died, compared to what the manufacturer estimated when writing the datasheet. However, the wear scale is likely significantly non-linear, so you can see a drive go from "50% used" to completely dead in a much shorter time than it took that same drive to go through the first 5 percent. So just interpret this as an arbitrary scale where "1%" means "brand new", "80%" means "will need replacement soon-ish".
